# What could be the direction of external force while bringing a body down with constant velocity in the earth's gravitation field?

Tags: work, potential-energy

This question arose from the idea of relating work done and gravitational potential energy. Textbooks say that we apply an external force in bringing a body from infinity towards the earth's surface with constant velocity i.e zero net acceleration or force. How can the net force be zero while applying an external force when there is already a gravitational force in the same direction? I mean there is no opposing force. Shouldn't the net force be a direct sum of gravitational force and the external force?

Comment: If you apply the external force in the opposite direction to gravity, it should work, no?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are right in saying that the net force will be a sum of the external force and the gravitational force. But, in the first place, to have zero net acceleration (or a constant velocity) you need to have a force directed opposite to the gravitational force. For example if the gravitational force is along the negative x axis, then the external force should be along positive x axis and should be of the same magnitude. Thus, you will be having no acceleration, and just slowly moving towards the earth's surface.

Answer (score 0):

When someone jumps out of a plane with a parachute (which we hope results in "constant velocity"), which way is the force of the parachute pulling on the person? When net force (sum of gravitational plus external) is exactly zero, the velocity will be constant.